# How to display internal images in javascript inside html

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my problem, I am using this responsive stylish menu that I found on codepen for the site I'm working on and modified it a little. The images being used in the website is being outsourced through a link. However, I would like to use the images I have on my folder. The path `images/folders/thepicture.jpg` seems to not work. How do I replace the external link to an internal one?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/xq7Lzrha/3/) is what I am working on:

Here is the code within the html file that confuses me. I do not know how to change this part. (Yes, I added the .js file inside the html file because separating it won't work on my localhost

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var isSelected = false;
const myProjects = [
  {
    ID: "-balmainParis",
    category: "Balmain Paris",
    bImage: "http://twofeetmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/web-designer.jpg",
    copy:
      "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. Nulla eu. In ipsum ac ultrices eget pretium, dictum velit a. Arcu aliquam nunc consectetuer. Mauris quisque interdum integer mauris fusce. Quam tellus molestie lobortis at diam, ut ac suscipit ante purus, auctor nec iaculis libero leo i</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p>"
  },
```

What should i put in **bImage** for my code to use the local images that I have?

Here is the folder Format I am using : 
[image: Main folder]

[image: images folder]

Comment: You need to serve your images. You can't just put them in a folder, drop your HTML file in the browser and hope that the images will be displayed. You need a back-end, a server that will receive images URL requests from the browser and repond with images to be displayed.

Comment: can you share your folder structure?

Comment: @UdaraKasun yes I'll add it to the post.

Comment: @JeremyThille This is the file composition that I always do and it seems to work on my other projects. I am just not familiar with javascript that much

Comment: where is your "brands" folder ? as you mentioned in jsfiddle? please check line number 33. i think it should be "brand" (images/brand/yourimage.jpg)

Comment: I'm sorry, I think i know where I went wrong, Thanks @UdaraKasun for pointing that out. It seems that i have been using brands. Can you put that in the answer so that I can approve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change your folder name "brans" to "brand"

```
    var isSelected = false;
    const myProjects = [
      {
        ID: "-balmainParis",
        category: "Balmain Paris",
        bImage: "images/brand/yourimage.jpg",
        copy:
          "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vehicula ullamco vel nullam, non vulputate purus sit vel est, egestas nec a.</p> <p>Curabitur rutrum, pellentesque ipsum hendrerit. </p>"
      },
```